# In Dos batch file press ENTER key to open program or press any other key to exit from bat

Tags: dos, batch-file

I have a DOS batch file that show some results on the cmd console.  I want users to press Enter to run program or press any other key on the keyboard to exit.

I don't want to use options/choices because in that case user will have to enter at least something which I need to check and set the action.

Example:
At the end of the cmd console something say like this
Press ENTER to open abc.exe or press any key on the keyboard to exit!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this

```
@ECHO OFF
SET Choice=
SET /P Choice=Press enter to open abc.exe (and something else to quit)
IF "%Choice%"=="" GOTO Start
GOTO End
:Start
echo abc.exe about to start
abc.exe
:End
```

EDIT: If you want just "any key" without pressing enter then this is impossible with the DOS scripting language but you could write a little exe utility who will do that for you.

Here is how it looks:

```
C:\Users\hol>test
Press enter to open abc.exe (and something else to quit)
```

If you press "enter" then we get:

```
C:\Users\hol>test2
Press enter to open abc.exe (and something else to quit)
abc.exe about to start
'abc.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\Users\hol>
```

I have not abc.exe so there is an error message. The other way around

```
C:\Users\hol>test2
Press enter to open abc.exe (and something else to quit)x
```

gives

```
C:\Users\hol>test2
Press enter to open abc.exe (and something else to quit)x

C:\Users\hol>
```

Basically set /p ask the user to specify the value of "Choice" when it is just enter then it is an empty string and we can start otherwise we end. Change it around for your liking.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but in this way user has to "enter something and then press ENTER" to quit, which is not the requirement. For quit as soon as user press any key it should EXIT. Can you please let me know if there is any solution.

Comment: Have you tried this code? Please test it out. If the user presses just enter then the program starts with abc.exe. if the user enters something the program quits.

Comment: I added you the test results.

Comment: Also I changed the code a little bit by using quotes instead of apostrophes which prevents an error message when the entered string starts with a blank.

Comment: Thanks for such a nice explanation, so I will go ahead with this because as you said it is not possible to in dos to quit on any key enter.  Here one more question, can I restrict user to press only just x or X only for quit? Thanks very much.

Comment: If you use the CHOICE command you could. choice /c:yq /m " Press y to go ahead or q to quit (y/q) " then next line "IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO GOAHEAD". By the way, do not forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

The batch file below will do exactly what you want:

```
   @rem ========================================
   @rem GETKEY.BAT - Written by Paul Tomasi 2010
   @rem
   @rem Waits for keypress. Returns key value
   @rem ========================================
   @echo off
      set /p .=Press ENTER to open abc.exe (and something else to quit): <nul
      call :getkey
      if %errorlevel% equ 13 start /b /wait abc.exe
   exit /b


   ::---------------------------
   :: GETKEY
   ::---------------------------
   :getkey
      (
         echo a
         echo mov ah, 08
         echo int 21
         echo mov ah, 4c
         echo int 21
         echo.
         echo rcx
         echo 08
         echo n getkey.com
         echo w
         echo q
      )>script
      debug<script>nul
      call getkey.com
   goto :eof
```

If your version of DOS does not support the 'SET /P' option (used merely to suppress the cursor dropping down to the next line) then simply replace this line with an ECHO statement.

You can omit the '/wait' if you want to drop straight through your batch file.